# get max string value in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, max

I have an array that contains string with the following format:

```
1-a1,1-a2,1-a3,1-a4,2-b1,2-b2,2-b3,2-b4,3-c1,3-c2,3-c3,4-d1,4-d2
```

where `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are numbers.

Now, how can I get the max value of `a`, max value of `b`, max value of `c`, max value of `d` in this array?

Comment: '1-61,1-62,1-63,1-64,2-31,2-32,2-33,2-34,3-71,3-72,3-73,4-71,4-72' what result will you want in this sample ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir i think he wants a = 6, b = 3, c = 7, d = 7

Comment: no the result should be a = 64, b = 34, c = 73 and d = 72 also the it is not a string, it is an array contains string elements

Comment: @Omran thats the result you want http://jsfiddle.net/UQWLe/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this much about regex, but try this:

```
var numbers = [0, 0, 0, 0]; //a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, d = 3

string.replace(/(\d)-(\d+)(,|$)/g, function($0, $1, $2) { numbers[parseInt($1) - 1] = Math.max(parseInt($2), numbers[parseInt($1) - 1]); });
```

Edit: I didn't know it was an array and what the result should be... . So here is my solution to your problem:

```
var numbers = [0, 0, 0, 0], i, j;

for(i=0,j=array.length;i<j;++i) {
    array[i] = array[i].split('-');

    numbers[parseInt(array[i][0]) - 1] = Math.max(numbers[parseInt(array[i][0]) - 1], parseInt(array[i][1]));
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UQWLe/1/

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming your array is ordered as you shown, and "1-a1" means "group 1, number, index 1" (and "1-a4" means "group 1, number, "index 4" and "2-b1" means "group 2, number, index 1" and so on); and assuming that all the parts could be more than one number (like "11-8812" aka "group 11, a number like 88 and an index like 12"); you could have something like:

```
var array = ["1-81","1-102","1-93","1-24","2-881","2-122","2-13","2-984","3-2121","3-12","3-93","4-41","4-22"]
var max = {};

var group = "", count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var parts = array[i].split("-");

    if (group !== parts[0]) {
        group = parts[0];
        count = 0;
    }

    count++;

    var number = +parts[1].replace(new RegExp(count + "$"), "");

    max[group] = Math.max(max[group] || 0, number)
}

console.log(max)
```

You can also use an array instead of an object for `max`. The whole procedure could be simplified if the last number is *always* one character.